# using Linux instead of UNIX to compile c code for CS course

Tags: c, linux, unix, gnu

A CS course I'm taking online suggests students compile their source code and run tools like valgrind on the OS UNIX.  I'm completely new to UNIX, Linux, their tools, and coding in c. I've made some attempts at installing FreeBSD 8.1 on VMWare Player 3.1.3, and even managed to get VMWare Tools running. But the FreeBSD documentation has led me down many dead-ends in accomplishing common tasks i.e. mounting an NFS or USB device. It turns out that the packages I need to make this happen aren't installed or configured, and I don't see any straight answer on how to install them.

So, if I'm using UNIX only as a tool to run gcc, g++, valgrind for this CS course, and these can be run on Linux instead, it seems like I can get the job done faster using Ubuntu Linux.

Can Linux be used to compile and run c code identically on UNIX, if compiled on Linux? Or if not, what are the differences to look for?

Thanks

Comment: Just now found out that Remote X is offered by the course as Xming for Windows, for this very reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the novice-level C programmer such as OP, the difference of environment is negligible. Go ahead with Linux.

Comment: Sigh of relief. The answer I wanted to hear. Hope so :)

Answer (score 1):

I think for purposes of the course you could run your programs and tools on Linux,

but I guess the reason your teacher wants you to use FreeBSD is so that you learn other things besides just coding up your problems

Comment: FreeBSD is actually rather user-friendly once you understand the basics. Read the Handbook (http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/), it's a great piece of documentation. To install ports use portsnap to fetch the ports tree, cd into /usr/ports/<category>/<portname> and run "make install" to install it. Install portmaster for a nicer interface. If you want FreeBSD with a simple installation and everything set up for you, use PC-BSD (http://www.pcbsd.org/). You'll find Valgrind in /usr/ports/devel/valgrind . You can find ports via Freshports - http://www.freshports.org . Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just now found out that Remote X is offered by the course as Xming for Windows, for this very reason. Ha, that would have saved me some grief!

Answer (score 1):

The two should be effectively the same. The only major difference you might see would be due to different versions being used. I would check to see what versions of gcc, g++ and valgrind the teacher is having you use, and make sure that you have the same version running on your install of Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).  You mentioned VMWare, so I'm guessing you're trying to just get an environment up and running in a windows environment.  They both allow you to use the compiler and some of the tools without  a full install of a Linux based system.  In a CS course they would be more than enough.

Comment: can mingw or cygwin host a valgrind?

Comment: No, I don't believe either of them can, but I'm not 100% certain.  It looks like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/) is built from sources, but I have never done it for this tool.

Comment: Have you heard of cmake? From glancing at their home page, it seems like it allows Windows-based c source files to be compiled to target a different platform i.e. UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

The main differences too look for:

1. Compiling C / C++ is not machine independent.  You need to have a small environment to compile on UNIX anyway if you need to submit compiled programs to your professor.
2. C / C++ is rather portable *if you don't use anything that's non-portable*.  It's very hard to verify that you didn't use something that's different between the two machines, so you may wish to compile on UNIX to verify you didn't let an unavailable library (or an specific to the OS procedure, argument, behavior, bugs, etc.) slip into your code.
3. The vendor of `make` between the two machines may differ.  This means that while the core of `make` will operate similarly, certain features might not be available in both.  In reality, you probably won't use most of `make`s extended features, but in a worst case scenario you might opt to maintain multiple `Makefile`s or limit yourself to a common subset of features.

At the end of the day, it all boils down to what your professor will want.  Odds are 95+% that you can do 100% of the work in Linux, but the prof's requirements or grading environment might be such that you will have to copy your code into a UNIX account to build the final "submission" executable.  Considering that university UNIX accounts aren't nearly as portable as Linux on a laptop, the cost of the "final verification / porting" to the University computer is likely to be small compared to the convenience of working on your homework more hours than you can manage in a fixed lab.

Comment: Exactly, I expect to be doing most of my coding from home, and not in the fully-configured lab environment with TAs to assist. Looks like I'll go with the cost of porting my code to a remote UNIX machine, instead of spinning my wheels on UNIX installation.